# Using tf.metrics.mean_iou during training

Tags: metrics, tensorflow-estimator

I want to train a model using the tensorflow estimator and want to track multiple metrics during training end evaluation. The metrics i want to track are accruacy and mean intersection-over-union (and my loss).

I managed to figure out how to track the accuracy during training:

```
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
   ...
   accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=indices_ground_truth, predictions=indices_prediction, name='acc_op')
   tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy[1])
```

and evaluation:

```
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
   ...
   accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=indices_ground_truth, predictions=indices_prediction)
   eval_metric_ops = {'accuracy': accuracy}

   return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)
```

For evaluation the mean intersection over union works the same. So its actually:

```
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
   ...
   miou = tf.metrics.mean_iou(labels=indices_ground_truth, predictions=indices_prediction, num_classes=13)
   accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=indices_ground_truth, predictions=indices_prediction)
   eval_metric_ops = {'miou': miou,
                      'accuracy': accuracy}

   return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)
```

As far as i know i have to track the update operation (the second return value) on the value during training. Otherwise it returns 0 every time. For a single value like the accuracy that works.

But for the miou the second return value is the update operation of the confusion matrix used to calculate the miou. Thats a [numClass,numClass] tensor. If i try to track it like the accuracy `tf.summary.scalar('miou', miou[1])` it crashes because a [numClass,numClass] tensor is not a scalar.

`tf.summary.scalar('miou', miou[0])` gives me 0s everytime.
So how can i give the miou to the summary?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I calculate the IoU while training:

```
mIoU, update_op = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_mean_iou(predict, raw_gt, num_classes=2, weights=None)
    tf.summary.scalar('meanIoU', mIoU)

confusion_matrix, _ = sess.run([update_op, train_op], feed_dict=feed_dict)
iou = sess.run(mIoU)

print('iou score = {:.3f}, ({:.3f} sec/step)'.format(iou, duration))
```

You don't need to track the confusion matrix output to track the IoU on tensorboard. The above works fine for me. I think, what you are missing is running the tensors in your session. You need to run update_op such as sess.run(update_op), while running metric operations as sess.run(iou)

Comment: And how do i use it in an estimator model_fn? I can't run a session in it or can i?